# is searchlist is empty shows not found

Tags: android

```
private void getSearchList()
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"getSearchList enter()");
        getBG = fetchBloodgroup.getSelectedItem().toString();
        getCity= fetchCity.getSelectedItem().toString();
        getCondition = getBG.concat(getCity);
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("profile").orderByChild("userCondition").equalTo(getCondition);
        FirebaseListOptions<UserProfile> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<UserProfile>().setLayout(R.layout.customlistview)
                .setQuery(query,UserProfile.class).build();


        listAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Object model, int position) {
                        UserProfile userProfile = (UserProfile) model;
                        TextView name = v.findViewById(R.id.customName);
                        TextView mobile = v.findViewById(R.id.customMobile);
                        TextView BG = v.findViewById(R.id.customBg);
                        TextView email = v.findViewById(R.id.customEmail);
                        TextView city = v.findViewById(R.id.customCity);

                         name.setText("Name:"+userProfile.getUserName().toString());
                        mobile.setText("Mobile No:"+userProfile.getUserMobileNo().toString());
                        BG.setText("BloodGroup:"+userProfile.getUserBloodgroup().toString());
                        email.setText("Email Id:"+userProfile.getUserEmailId().toString());
                        city.setText("Location:"+userProfile.getUserCity().toString());

            }
        };

            searchLV.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listAdapter.startListening();

            Log.d(TAG,"getSearchList exit()");
    }
```

I want to add some code to check if search listview searchlv is empty shows toast message data not found. If data is not found in database it shows toast message not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using

```
if (listAdapter.getCount() <= 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: options.size()  this function is not available

Comment: this is also not working size of listadapter always show zero in all conditions.

Comment: According to documentation it should work, check getCount() method on this link https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/androidchat/FirebaseListAdapter.java.